# Apache Flink: What's the difference between side outputs and split() in the DataStream API?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Apache Flink has a `split` API that lets to branch data-streams:

```
val splited = datastream.split { i => i match {
   case i if ... => Seq("red", "blue")
   case _ => Seq("green")
}}

splited.select("green").flatMap { .... }
```

It also provides a another approach called Side Output( https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/side_output.html) that lets you do the same thing!

What's the difference between these two way? Do they use from a same lower-level construction? Do they cost the same? When and how we should select one of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `split` operator is part of the DataStream API since its early days. The side output feature as added later and offers a superset of `split`'s functionality.

`split` creates multiple streams of the same type, the input type. Side outputs can be of any type, i.e., also different from the input and the main output.

Internally, `split` adds dedicated operator that just splits the stream. Side outputs are defined within an operator (typically a `ProcessFunction` or window operator) that apply arbitrary logic and feature multiple outputs. I would not expect this to result in a significant performance difference.

A common use case for side outputs is to filter out invalid (or late) records and pass them unmodified to the side, e.g., to process them later. Such an operator has a regular output with the desired result type and a side output with its input type. This logic would be cumbersome to implement using `split`.

Comment: So as I understand the side-output is a more flexible way with same runtime cost! Am I right?

Comment: @Fabian: Is there a way to use the same without ProcessFunction or window operator? For example: assume the use case is - stream the data from one source to multiple sink based on condition. ie - There is no any intermediate logic that the sideOutput supports now ([here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/)) - No keyBy, Process, CoProcess, etc. How to achieve side output for this specific case?

Answer (score 3):

One important difference between [`split`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#split-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.collector.selector.OutputSelector-) and [side outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/side_output.html) is that `split` [is deprecated](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#split-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.collector.selector.OutputSelector-) while side outputs are not.

Quote from Flink's `split` [manual](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#i49):

```
split(OutputSelector<T> outputSelector)
Deprecated. 
Please use side output instead.
```